# How I can update item of tableview on certain position swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

I have tableview in my app and after clicking any item from this list I move to smth like detail view in this function:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
        self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
        
        
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Fruitslist", bundle: nil)
        guard let details = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "DetailView") as? DetailView else { return }
        
        
        details.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        details.delegate = self
        
        self.show(details, sender: nil)
        
        
    }
```

in this detail view I have protocol:

```
protocol AddToNotepad {
    func addToNotepadFunc(added:Bool)
}
```

when I move to main list from this detail screen I send some data:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        
        if self.isMovingFromParent {
            self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false
            self.delegate?.addToNotepadFunc(added: true)
        }
    }
```

in my main list I receive this data in extension:

```
extension FruitList:AddToNotepad{
    func addToNotepadFunc(added: Bool) {
        let indexPath = IndexPath(item: 1, section: 2)
        if let fruitCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? FruitListCell {
            
            fruitCell.eTitle.text = "232332322332"
        }
    }
    
}
```

and I don't understand how to update some part of cell in certain section. I also can send section in detail view but how to update certain element of cell on certain section I can't understand :( You can see my attempt but it doesn't work. Maybe someone knows where I did some errors?

Comment: @Frankenstein, because it was stupid mistake which was caused by me :) I think that this question won't help this skills database, but of course I can restore it if you think that this question will be useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you set a static indexpath here

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(item: 1, section: 2)
```

While you should

```
var lastIndex:IndexPath!
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
  lastIndex = indexPath
  .....
}
```

Then  use it to update the model inside `addToNotepadFunc`  like

```
array[lastIndex.section][lastIndex.row].added = true
// refresh table at that indexpath
self.tableView.reloadRows(at:[lastIndex],with:.none)
```

Comment: I understand it, it smth like testing)) of course I will set selected last selected index, but I can't change title of selected cell after some actions on detail screen, here is the problem right now, but thank you for pointing on another problem :)

Comment: @Andrew i assume that above answer is for your whole question can you elaborate if there is another issue ??

Comment: Yes above answer is for whole question, I'm looking for smth like `notifyItemChanged(position,payload)` at android recyclerview :) I needn't refreshing whole list but I would like to refresh one certain item on certain cell. maybe this info will help you :)

Comment: you need `reloadRows` see edit but first you have to update the data source

Comment: so, as I see I can't update cell without updating data source?

Comment: yes as cells are re-used so the dataSource will guarantee that last change is here unlike accessing the cell out of `cellForRowAt` which temporarily updates the cell until the user scrolls and this will cause it to get old data source data in case you didn't update it

Comment: but after updating row I see such warning `Warning once only: UITableView was told to layout its visible cells and other contents without being in the view hierarchy (the table view or one of its superviews has not been added to a window). This may cause bugs by forcing views inside the table` this is critical or not?